# How to clone a table schema (including indices) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, scripting

Is there a command that will completely clone the schema of a table?  This would include all constraints, foreign keys, and indices on the table.

In SSMS the *Script Table as | Create To* menu command does not include indices defined on the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the behavior of *Script Table As*, use *Tools | Options | SQL Server Object Explorer | Scripting | Table and view options* as [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) originally suggested in a comment.

[image: Options]

Alternatively, if you want to script out multiple objects at the same time, you want to use the *Generate Scripts* functionality.  Right click on the database in question, select *Tasks --> Generate Scripts*.  Then the wizard will walk you through further options.  You can even have it script out the data.

[image: Generate Scripts]

You can select all objects of a type, or specific objects to be scripted. By default, some parts of the database aren't scripted, including some things you might expect - like statistics contents.